# TypeError: date.getDate is not a function ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a date picker and basically, it returns the format like this: YYYY-MM-DD

But I need to parse it to format "DD/MM/YYYY" and I am using this function: function

```
convertDateFormat(date) {
    return String(date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear())
}
```

So also I am calling this function when I dispatch my data

```
dispatch(Order(convertDateFormat(inputs.datePickerdate)));
```

but I am getting this error: TypeError: date.getDate is not a function
Do you have any idea that I can do it in react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your date argument is being passed in as a string rather than a JavaScript Date object. You can either pass in a Date object directly or handle this inside the convertDateFormat function as follows:

```
convertDateFormat(dateString) {
  const date = new Date(dateString);

  return String(date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value you are passing to function would be string.
can you add
var newDate = new Date(date);

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You need to create a `Date` object from the given date, in order to use `getDate()` and other functions.

```
convertDateFormat(date) {
    date = new Date(date);
    return String(date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me-

```
new Date(inputDate).toLocaleDateString("en-US",{day:'numeric', month:'long', year:"numeric", timeZone:"PST"})
```